# MBA displays the Question mark Folder on booting up

Tags: macbook-pro

All of a sudden MBA boots displaying question mark folder. I've tried booting from a USB OS X to use disk utility but can't see the Macintosh HD of the Air to fix the disk. Safe mode doesn't seem to work. Any root-cause? Any solution?

Comment: When booted from USB, try running System Information (it's the first choice under the Apple menu if you hold the Option key). Select the bus your internal disk is attached to (should be either ATA or SATA, depending on which version of MP Air you have) and see if it sees the disk (and if so, what it thinks its properties are).

Comment: hi Gordon I don't see that option on OSX Utilities

Comment: If you're starting from a recovery drive rather than full OS X (i.e. you only get the "OS X Utilities" window, not the full Finder interface), System Information is not available. Sorry...

Comment: I just have a recovery drive indeed, I was able to use safari can go online , though there s no much I can do , no sites that can revive my Mac HD

Comment: My guess would be a hardware failure, but it's hard to confirm without better diagnostic tools than what's available in recovery mode.

Comment: Sent the Air to Apple Care, let see. FYI I also didnt see  " System Information (it's the first choice under the Apple menu if you hold the Option key). " .. while doing a remote booting using Wifi..  I appreciate your following on this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question mark folder usually means:

1. The hard disk is failing or has failed
2. Your Mac can't find a System Folder to boot from

Try starting up while holding down the Alt/Option key. That should prompt the Startup Manager window where you can select the startup disk.

[image]

If that doesn't help, refer to this [Apple KB Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1440).

Comment: Thanks for tips Guys,though ,as I mentioned before I can't even see my Macintosh HD drive while using USB OS booting drive ,accessing thru Disk Utility. Network Remote doesn't work after setting the wifi, I'm just wondering if there s no other options besides the above.